# How do you create a class in one unit, and use it as a return type in another unit?

Tags: delphi, class, oop, object

So I can do this quickly and simply in Java but I think I'm missing something when trying to do it in Delphi. I have a unit called DlgDXFImporterEllipse that looks as follows:

```
unit DlgDXFImporterEllipse;

interface

uses Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, Windows;

type
  TDlgDXFImporterEllipse = class(TObject)

private
  centre : TCoord;
  radius : double;
  startAngle : double;
  endAngle : double;

public
  constructor Create(cent: TCoord; rad, startA, endA: double);

  function GetCentre : TCoord;
  function GetRadius : Double;
  function GetStartAngle : Double;
  function GetEndAngle : Double;
  procedure print;
end;

var
  test: TDlgDXFImporterEllipse;

implementation

constructor TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.Create(cent : TCoord; rad,startA,endA : Double);
begin
  centre := cent;
  radius := rad;
  startAngle := startA;
  endAngle := endA;
end;

function TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.GetCentre : TCoord;
begin
  Result := centre;
end;

function TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.GetRadius : Double;
begin
  Result := radius;
end;

function TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.GetStartAngle : Double;
begin
  Result := startAngle;
end;

function TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.GetEndAngle : Double;
begin
  Result := endAngle;
end;

procedure TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.print;
begin
  Writeln(Output, 'Test Print');
end;

end.
```

I now want to create this class as an object in another unit called DlgDXFImporter:

```
unit DlgDFXImporter;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, DlgDXFImporterEllipse;

type
  TDlgDXFImport = class(TForm)
  private
    Ellipse: TDlgDXFImporterEllipse;
    function GetEllipseDxfValues(CurLine, NextLine, prevObj, lastObj: String) : Ellipse;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TDlgDXFImport.GetEllipseDxfValues(CurLine, NextLine, prevObj, lastObj: String): Ellipse ;
var
  centre : TCoord;
  temp : Ellipse ;
begin

centre.x := 5.1;
centre.y := 80.25;
temp := Ellipse.Create(centre, 50, 82.45, 28.15);
temp.print;
Result := temp;

end;
```

I'm getting the following error:
[DCC Error] DlgDFXImporter.pas(1752): E2005 'Ellipse' is not a type identifier
I'm really not familiar enough with the Delphi syntax to find what I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is returning `Ellipse`, but that's not the name of the class you defined - perhaps you meant `TDlgDXFImporterEllipse`?

```
function GetEllipseDxfValues(
   CurLine, NextLine, prevObj, lastObj: String) : Ellipse;
```

Should be:

```
function GetEllipseDxfValues(
   CurLine, NextLine, prevObj, lastObj: String) : TDlgDXFImporterEllipse;
```

Comment: Under the DlgDXFImported class, in the private section, I have this: Ellipse: TDlgDXFImporterEllipse;. Would that not work?

Comment: That declares a field named `Ellipse` of type `TDlgDXFImporterEllipse` - it doesn't rename the class

Comment: You speak the truth, will try it out quickly :)

Comment: If I recall, you can add `Ellipse = TDlgDXFImporterEllipse` to the `type` section if you want to do call it something else within that unit.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Create` method of the class, not the instance, in your case, the variable `Ellipse` is an instance of the class `TDlgDXFImporterEllipse`

so the correct code would be:

```
function TDlgDXFImport.GetEllipseDxfValues(CurLine, NextLine, prevObj, lastObj: String): TDlgDXFImporterEllipse
var
  centre : TCoord;

begin
 centre.x := 5.1;
 centre.y := 80.25;
 Result := TDlgDXFImporterEllipse.Create(centre, 50, 82.45, 28.15);
end;
```

if you want a generic `TEllipse` type, then you should create a new unit, defining this type and inherit your `TDlgDXFImporterEllipse` from `TEllipse`

Comment: Yep, the answer above said the same thing, but thank you too.